# CSS Selectors using withStyle HOC from material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui with Reactjs and for styles i choosed to use withStyles HOC to style my components , the problem is that I don't know how to translate complex selectors from CSS to React Style ,

```
const Styles ={
  label :{
      width:"100%"
  },

  cardInputRadio:{
      display:"none",
      '&:checked + .cardInput': {
        color: 'green',
        display:"block"
     }
  },

  cardInput:{
      margin:"10px",
    '&:hover': {
        cursor: 'pointer',

     },
    'cardInputRadio:checked+ &':{
        color:'red',
     }

  },
  container:{
      flexGrow:1,
  },
  card: {
    minWidth: 100,
    width:300,
    display:"inline-block"
  },

     title: {
      fontSize: 14,
     },

   } ;
```

That's what I'm doing now , and of course I'm using

```
export default withStyles(Styles)(MyComponent);
```

as you can see I am trying to translate this css to react Style

```
.card-input-element:checked + .card-input {
     box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #2e0071;
 }
```

I want to change the card color when the radio button is checked , but I can't do it with Material UI style HOC 
Thank you

Comment: The main thing I see missing is that when referring to another style rule in the same style sheet (i.e. created with the same `withStyles` call), you need to use `$` (e.g. `$cardInputRadio`). Please review some of my related answers and the JSS documentation they link to for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7495930+jss-plugin-nested

Comment: Here's a direct link to the JSS documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet

Answer (score 0):

One way to add conditional styles is with the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library.

Assuming your component has a 'checked' prop, your styles would be along the lines of

```
cardInputRadio:{
  display:"none"
},
cardInputRadioChecked: {
  color: 'green',
  display: 'block'
}
```

And in your component you define your classNames something like this

```
import classNames from 'classnames'

const MyInputRadioComponent ...
  const { checked } = props
  const classNames = classNames({
    [styles.cardInputRadio]: true,
    [styles.cardInputRadioChecked]: checked
  })

  return <YourRadioComponent classNames={classNames}/>
```